# Macro to separate sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a Macro that will separate out the data in a spreadsheet ordered by Column A into separate sheets to ensure that the indexes in Column A are unique in each sheet.  It would do this by putting the first row with a given Column A value into the first occurrence sheet, the second row with the same column A value into the second occurrence sheet and so on.  Then when it finds a new Column A value it would put the first row into the first occurrence sheet and the second row into the second occurrence sheet and so on as shown in the pictures.  Note that, the text values of Column B in the pictures are for illustration only and in general, Column B will not have any pattern  [image: main sheet][image: first occurrence sheet][image: secound occurrence sheet][image: third occurrence sheet]  The data I am trying to apply this to looks like this.[image]

Comment: Where specifically are you stuck in implementing this?

Comment: I am working on code right now, but I am a little out of practice in VBA, and I was looking for some help getting started.

Comment: `=COUNTIFS($A$1:A1,A1)` in a new column will give you the index of the sheet that each element in A should be copied to, e.g. 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3.

Comment: What's your issue?

Comment: When I try code snippet1 it works on the example, but on my data which is now added to the question, I get a "Insert method of range class failed".   I am wondering how I can generalize the code snippet the the new data.

Comment: It's important to provide sample data that follows the same pattern as your actual data when creating a post. This will help save both your time and the time of those providing assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: Filter and copy data to new sheet

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub demo1()
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet, desSht As Worksheet
    Dim objDic As Object, c As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey
    Dim arrData
    Const COL_COUNT = 3  ' number of columns in source table
    Const COL_KEY = 3 ' column as the source of unique key
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    Set srcSht = Sheets("Sheet2") ' Modify as needed
    srcSht.Rows(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    srcSht.Range("A1").Resize(1, COL_COUNT).Value = "COLX"
    With srcSht.Range("A1").Resize(1, COL_COUNT).CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter
        arrData = .Value
        Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
            sKey = arrData(i, COL_KEY)
            objDic(sKey) = ""
        Next i
        For Each sKey In objDic.keys
            .AutoFilter Field:=COL_KEY, Criteria1:=sKey
            Set c = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                On Error Resume Next
                Set desSht = Sheets(sKey)
                On Error GoTo 0
                If desSht Is Nothing Then
                    Set desSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
                    desSht.Name = sKey
                Else
                    desSht.Cells.Clear
                End If
                c.Copy desSht.Cells(1, 1)
                desSht.Rows(1).Delete
                Set desSht = Nothing
            End If
        Next
    End With
    srcSht.Rows(1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    srcSht.Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

Option 2: If you prefer to get it done w/o copy/paste, please try below code.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub demo2()
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet, desSht As Worksheet
    Dim objDic As Object
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Integer, sKey, lastKey
    Dim arrData, arrRes(), rowCount As Long, colCount As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set srcSht = Sheets("Sheet2") ' Modify as needed
    ' Sort data
    With srcSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .Sort key1:=.Columns(2), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
        ' Load data
        arrData = .Value
    End With
    rowCount = UBound(arrData)
    colCount = UBound(arrData, 2)
    ' Get unique list of column B with Dcit object
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To rowCount
        sKey = arrData(i, 2)
        If Not objDic.Exists(sKey) Then
            objDic(sKey) = ""
            If Len(lastKey) > 0 Then
                ' Store data in Dict
                ReDim Preserve arrRes(1 To colCount, 1 To j - 1)
                objDic(lastKey) = Application.Transpose(arrRes)
            End If
            lastKey = sKey
            ReDim arrRes(1 To colCount, 1 To rowCount)
            j = 1
        End If
        For k = 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)
            arrRes(k, j) = arrData(i, k)
        Next
        j = j + 1
    Next i
    ' Store the last piece of data
    ReDim Preserve arrRes(1 To colCount, 1 To j - 1)
    objDic(lastKey) = Application.Transpose(arrRes)
    For Each sKey In objDic.keys
        ' Create new sheet or clear the exist sheet
        On Error Resume Next
        Set desSht = Sheets(sKey)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If desSht Is Nothing Then
            Set desSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
            desSht.Name = sKey
        Else
            desSht.Cells.Clear
        End If
        ' Write data to sheet
        arrRes = objDic(sKey)
        desSht.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(arrRes), colCount).Value = arrRes
        Set desSht = Nothing
    Next
    srcSht.Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Please update OP with your sample data. Which code snippet are you using?

Comment: I am using code snippet 1.

Comment: I have updated `Option 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Collection Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/collection-object)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SplitData()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim co As Collection, dict As Object, id
    Dim lastrow As Long, r As Long, n As Long, i As Long
    Dim x As Long, j As Long, arSht, arRow() As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' group each id in collections
    With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 2 To lastrow ' assume header in row 1
            id = Trim(.Cells(r, "A"))
            If Not dict.exists(id) Then
                 dict.Add id, New Collection
            End If
            dict(id).Add r, CStr(r)
            ' max instances
            If dict(id).Count > x Then x = dict(id).Count
        Next
    End With
    
    ' check enough sheets
    If wb.Sheets.Count <= x Then
        MsgBox "Not enough sheets, need " & x + 1, vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' size arrays for each sheet
    ReDim arSht(1 To x)
    ReDim arRow(1 To x)
    Dim arTemp
    For n = 1 To x
        arRow(n) = 0
        ReDim arTemp(1 To dict.Count, 1 To 3)
        arSht(n) = arTemp
    Next
    
    ' fill array
    For Each id In dict
        For n = 1 To dict(id).Count
            
            ' next array index for sheet
            arRow(n) = arRow(n) + 1
            i = arRow(n)
        
            ' src row
            r = dict(id)(n)
            
            ' copy 3 columns from sheet
            For j = 1 To 3
                arSht(n)(i, j) = ws.Cells(r, j).Value2
            Next
        Next
    Next
    
    ' copy to sheets
    For n = 1 To x
        Sheets(n + 1).Cells.Clear
        Sheets(n + 1).Range("A1:C3").Resize(dict.Count) = arSht(n)
    Next
    MsgBox x & " Sheets updated", vbInformation

End Sub
```